# Bulding Deep Learning model for multiclassification case

Tags: python, deep-learning, multiclass-classification, optimization, parameter

I am soo confused i read a lot of information in forumas and still cna't get what is wrong.
my data is around 500.000 rows and 32 columns. my target variables consists of 3 classes (0, 1, 2). Hyperopt supposed to get best parameters that fit my data but no luck :/

```
# Define the objective function to minimize (in this case, negative accuracy)
def objective(params):
    model = Sequential()

    # Add input layer
    model.add(Dense(params['neurons_1'], input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation=params['activation'], kernel_regularizer=l2(params['l2'])))

    # Add hidden layers based on the optimized value
    for i in range(2, int(params['hidden_layers']) + 1):
        model.add(Dense(params[f'neurons_{i}'], activation=params['activation'], kernel_regularizer=l2(params['l2'])))

    # Add output layer
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))  # Adjust the output size based on your multiclass problem
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    # Define EarlyStopping callback
    early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', patience=5, restore_best_weights=True)

    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=60, batch_size=params['batch_size'], validation_data=(X_val, y_val), 
                        class_weight=dict(enumerate(class_weights)), verbose=0, callbacks=[early_stopping])
    val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy'][-1]
    return {'loss': -val_acc, 'status': STATUS_OK}

# Define the hyperparameter search space
space = {'hidden_layers': hp.quniform('hidden_layers', 1, 6, 1),  # Adjust the range as needed
         'learning_rate': hp.loguniform('learning_rate', np.log(1e-5), np.log(1e-3)),
         'l2': hp.loguniform('l2', np.log(1e-8), np.log(1e-3)),  # Use a default range
         'activation': hp.choice('activation', ['relu', 'tanh']),  # Add 'tanh' activation
         'batch_size': hp.choice('batch_size', [512, 1024, 2048, 4096])  # Add batch size options
        }

# Add neurons for input layer and each hidden layer
for i in range(1, 7):  #%%% Define with +1 because 1st layer is input one
    space[f'neurons_{i}'] = hp.choice(f'neurons_{i}', [8, 12, 24, 16, 32, 48, 64, 72, 96, 128])

# Use hyperopt to find the best hyperparameters
trials = Trials()
best = fmin(fn=objective, space=space, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=50, trials=trials)
```

[image]